# How does TCP Tell a server that i want to close the PIPE

Tags: python, networking, tcp

Lets say i have this python code:

```
pipe = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
pipe.connect((target, port))
pipe.send(b'hello world')
pipe.close()
```

How does TCP communicate that i want to close the pipe to the server?
Is there a way to spoof an closed pipe? Like sending the server an packet that says that the pipe is closed but its still open.

Comment: It sends a segment with the `FIN` flag set.

Comment: Are you trying to send EOF to the server, but still be able to read the response? Look at [`socket.shutdown()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown)

Comment: A socket is not a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

TCP creates a connection between peers. Client/server is an application concept.

Either TCP peer can send a FIN that tells the other TCP that it is done sending, but it can still receive and process data until the other end also sends a FIN to say it, too, is done sending. An application tells TCP it is done, then TCP sends a FIN to the other side.

Either side could also send a RST that immediately kills the connection.

*[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol, Section 3.5 Closing a Connection](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793#section-3.5)* goes into more detail:

> [3.5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793#section-3.5).
> Closing a Connection
>
> CLOSE is an operation meaning "I have no more data to send." The
> notion of closing a full-duplex connection is subject to ambiguous
> interpretation, of course, since it may not be obvious how to treat
> the receiving side of the connection. We have chosen to treat CLOSE in
> a simplex fashion. The user who CLOSEs may continue to RECEIVE until
> he is told that the other side has CLOSED also. Thus, a program could
> initiate several SENDs followed by a CLOSE, and then continue to
> RECEIVE until signaled that a RECEIVE failed because the other side
> has CLOSED. We assume that the TCP will signal a user, even if no
> RECEIVEs are outstanding, that the other side has closed, so the user
> can terminate his side gracefully. A TCP will reliably deliver all
> buffers SENT before the connection was CLOSED so a user who expects no
> data in return need only wait to hear the connection was CLOSED
> successfully to know that all his data was received at the destination
> TCP. Users must keep reading connections they close for sending until
> the TCP says no more data.
>
> There are essentially three cases:
>
> 1. The user initiates by telling the TCP to CLOSE the connection
> 2. The remote TCP initiates by sending a FIN control signal
> 3. Both users CLOSE simultaneously
>
> Case 1: Local user initiates the close
>
> In this case, a FIN segment can be constructed and placed on the
> outgoing segment queue. No further SENDs from the user will be
> accepted by the TCP, and it enters the FIN-WAIT-1 state. RECEIVEs  are
> allowed in this state. All segments preceding and including FIN  will
> be retransmitted until acknowledged.  When the other TCP has both
> acknowledged the FIN and sent a FIN of its own, the first TCP can ACK
> this FIN. Note that a TCP receiving a FIN will ACK but not send its
> own FIN until its user has CLOSED the connection also.
>
> Case 2: TCP receives a FIN from the network
>
> If an unsolicited FIN arrives from the network, the receiving TCP can
> ACK it and tell the user that the connection is closing. The user will
> respond with a CLOSE, upon which the TCP can send a FIN to the other
> TCP after sending any remaining data. The TCP then waits until its own
> FIN is acknowledged whereupon it deletes the connection. If an ACK is
> not forthcoming, after the user timeout the connection is aborted and
> the user is told.
>
> Case 3:  both users close simultaneously
>
> A simultaneous CLOSE by users at both ends of a connection causes FIN
> segments to be exchanged. When all segments preceding the FINs have
> been processed and acknowledged, each TCP can ACK the FIN it has
> received. Both will, upon receiving these ACKs, delete the connection.
>
> ```
>       TCP A                                                TCP B
>
>   1.  ESTABLISHED                                          ESTABLISHED
>
>   2.  (Close)
>       FIN-WAIT-1  --> <SEQ=100><ACK=300><CTL=FIN,ACK>  --> CLOSE-WAIT
>
>   3.  FIN-WAIT-2  <-- <SEQ=300><ACK=101><CTL=ACK>      <-- CLOSE-WAIT
>
>   4.                                                       (Close)
>       TIME-WAIT   <-- <SEQ=300><ACK=101><CTL=FIN,ACK>  <-- LAST-ACK
>
>   5.  TIME-WAIT   --> <SEQ=101><ACK=301><CTL=ACK>      --> CLOSED
>
>   6.  (2 MSL)
>       CLOSED
>
>                          Normal Close Sequence
>
>                                Figure 13.
>
>
>       TCP A                                                TCP B
>
>   1.  ESTABLISHED                                          ESTABLISHED
>
>   2.  (Close)                                              (Close)
>       FIN-WAIT-1  --> <SEQ=100><ACK=300><CTL=FIN,ACK>  ... FIN-WAIT-1
>                   <-- <SEQ=300><ACK=100><CTL=FIN,ACK>  <--
>                   ... <SEQ=100><ACK=300><CTL=FIN,ACK>  -->
>
>   3.  CLOSING     --> <SEQ=101><ACK=301><CTL=ACK>      ... CLOSING
>                   <-- <SEQ=301><ACK=101><CTL=ACK>      <--
>                   ... <SEQ=101><ACK=301><CTL=ACK>      -->
>
>   4.  TIME-WAIT                                            TIME-WAIT
>       (2 MSL)                                              (2 MSL)
>       CLOSED                                               CLOSED
>
>                       Simultaneous Close Sequence
>
>                                Figure 14.
> ```